# Sigma Delta modulator loop filter

Tags: adc, dac, transfer-function

how to determine the continuous time loop filter transfer function from discrete time loop transfer function.

Loop filter transfer function is

[image]

If DAC is of NRZ type  with 3 bit input how to get the transfer function in continuous domain?
Can I use ZOH for a 3 bit DAC? 
Can I use MATLAB d2c command for this conversion?

Comment: https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-43f2d184991033bf5f3b30a1e7bab33e

Comment: Nope. Simple d2c command won't help. There is something called an Impulse Invariant transform that we need to do. Here is the reference specific to sigma delta - https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7974157/ Also, the loop filter transfer function differs with the DAC pulse type, delay as well.

Comment: Also, could you post the model of the sigma delta modulator in discrete time domain and the exact DAC pulse? I will try to convert to the continuous time domain and post answer if possible.